# Getting Cloud Watch Logs according to the region in which I work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am monitoring application logs in Cloud Watch using custom metrics. I get those logs in UTC in Cloud Watch Logs. I work from India but I use the Sydney region because that is my client location.

As far as I know, there is a possibility of getting them either in UTC or our local time.When I select my local time, it shows according to Indian Standard Time.

Is there any possibility of getting those logs according to Sydney Timings? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that CloudWatch Logs is using the timezone configured in the web browser / computer.

For example, I accessed some CloudWatch Logs in Sydney (UTC+11) while I was in the Perth timezone (UTC+8), and the "Local Timezone" showed as Perth time.

So, please check the Regional Settings / Timezone of your computer and see which timezone it is configured to use.

Comment: The timezone has changed in the cloud watch logs. But, the time mentioned in the SNS notification is still in UTC. Is there any way to get it in Sydeney time (My local timezone)?

Comment: I don't think you can change the time shown in SNS.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a region setting into your local aws config which should be [userHome].aws\config:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1 
# please change to your region
```